# Cloudinary - Upload preset must be in whitelist for unsigned uploads

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ngcordova, cloudinary

I want to upload image, to Cloudinary, taken directly from camera in Ionic using cordova camera plugin. I am getting an error of code 1, having message "upload preset must be in whitelist for unsigned uploads."
How to solve this error.Please help.

my edited js code is:

```
    $scope.cameraopen = function(){
   var options = {
         quality : 100,
         destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,//FILE_URI
         sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
         allowEdit : false,
         encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
         popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
         targetWidth: 500,
         targetHeight: 500,
         saveToPhotoAlbum: true
     };
$cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {

var Uploadoptions = {
              upload_preset: cloudinary.config().upload_preset,
              tags: 'mytag',
              context: 'photo=photo', 
              file: imageData
            };

       var onUploadSuccess = function(data){
        console.log("success"+JSON.stringify(data));
       }
       var onUploadFail = function(e){
        console.log("error"+JSON.stringify(e));
       }

       var ft = new FileTransfer();
 ft.upload(imageData, "http://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/" + cloudinary.config().cloud_name + "/upload", onUploadSuccess, onUploadFail, Uploadoptions, true); 
    }, function(err) {
      // error
    });
}
```

Comment: what've you tried? Error code from what? Are you using certain application or just uploading via browser?

Comment: Can you check that all the necessary data was properly sent along with the POST request? Specifically it seems that the upload_preset is not properly sent, or is not correctly configured on your Cloudinary account (e.g. whitelisted as unsigned)

Comment: @ruchiYadav For more details, see: http://cloudinary.com/blog/direct_upload_made_easy_from_browser_or_mobile_app_to_the_cloud#duu

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to enable unsigned uploading for your Cloudinary account from the [Upload Settings page.](https://cloudinary.com/console/settings/upload)

[Please refer the blog post on direct uploads from the browser and check](https://cloudinary.com/blog/direct_upload_made_easy_from_browser_or_mobile_app_to_the_cloud#duu).  It can happen if some data necessary for the POST request is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You need to go **Cloudinary** > **Setting** > **Upload** >  **Presets**
then click edit and change into **UnSigned Upload **

Then Your Error 100% resolved. Please support us for work.

[image]